# Topics of analysis beyond in $\mathbb{R}$ and beyond of functions of single real variable?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, self-learning

Could someone list the topics of analysis beyond in $\mathbb{R}$ and beyond of functions of single real variable that a new math graduate student should be familiar with? Also could someone list the recommended/standard study materials for these topics? Thanks in advance!

**Edit1:** Precisely I wish to ask "the topics of analysis beyond in $\mathbb{R}$ and beyond of functions of single real variable that new math graduate students **are expected to be already familiar with**". Thanks for the comment for clarification by Mike Haskel.

**Edit2:** Sorry. This question is a cross-posting. The same question is asked in Reddit r/math here: https://redd.it/3ppxn9

Comment: Do you mean to ask what are the topics we should expect a new graduate student already knows, or to ask what topics we should try to teach them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're asking what a new student might be expected to know when they arrive at graduate school. A good start would be familiarity with the following topics, to the point where the student can do proof-based exercises without assistance.

Walter Rudin gives a good treatment of real analysis at this level in his *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (a.k.a. "Baby Rudin," ISBN 978-0070542358).

**Metric Spaces**

- Convergence, Cauchy sequences, and completeness.
- Continuity vs. uniform continuity vs. Lipschitz continuity.
- Pointwise vs. uniform convergence.

**Differentiation**

- Derivatives of functions $\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}$ as linear maps.
- Multivariable Taylor approximation.
- Inverse and implicit function theorems.

**Integration**

- Formal development of Riemann integration.

**Topology of $\mathbb{R}$**

- $\mathbb{R}$ is the unique realization of a certain list of axioms.
- Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem (closed and bounded iff sequentially compact).
- Heine-Borel theorem (closed and bounded iff topologically compact).
- Topological connectedness.

Comment: I've made the answer a community wiki, so anyone who can should feel free to add to or otherwise improve the list.

Comment: For analysis in general Euclidean space or vector space, do you still recommend following Baby Rudin only? I had heard of some educators commenting that this part (beginning from chapter 9) of Baby Rudin is too abstract and too terse to learn how to apply the theorems (ex. to do explicit computations).

Comment: @Tien-ChengHuang I think it's okay, provided that the student has already learned to do linear algebra and multivariable calculus. At the point someone is reading Baby Rudin, they should already know how to do the relevant computations, and now they're learning the theory behind it.

Comment: I found D.J.H. Garling's three volume (published in 2013-2014) is probably a complete answer to my question. The TOC is here: http://assets.cambridge.org/97811070/32026/toc/9781107032026_toc.pdf